# Lexical Environment блока

Tags: ecmascript

Спецификация говорит, что Lexical Environment (LE) - это запись какого-то Execution Context'а (EC) (см. [таблицу 22](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#table-23)).

Но в главе, посвященной самим LE также [говорится](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-lexical-environments), что отдельный LE создается также каждый раз при выполнении кода блока, кода функциональной декларации и кода catch-выражения.

При этом нигде не сказано, что при выполнении кода этих выражений создается новый EC.

Соответственно, тут возникает вопрос: если при начале исполнения кода вышеперечисленных выражений не создается нового EC, то с чем ассоциируются созданные для них LE? Или все-таки новый EC создается не только при выполнении кода функций (ну и кода работ, понятно)? Но в таком случае, почему его внутренние компоненты (таблица 21) не содержат ни одного обязательного компонента, посвященного чему-то кроме функций? Например, тому же блоку? Как трактовать написанное в спецификации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В спецификации для каждого из *statement* есть секция *Runtime Semantic*, в которой, как раз и описывается поведение.

На примере [BlockSatement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

Block:**{** *StatementList* **}**

1. Пусть *oldEnv* будет *LexicalEnvironment* текущего контекста выполнения.
2. Пусть blockEnv результат выполнения **NewDeclarativeEnvironment(oldEnv)**.
3. Выполнить *BlockDeclarationInstantiation(StatementList, blockEnv)*.
4. Установить **текущему** контексту выполнения blockEnv в качестве *LexicalEnvironment*.
5. Пусть *blockValue* будет результатом выполнения *StatementList*.
6. Установить *текущему* контексту выполнения *oldEnv* в качестве *LexicalEnvironment*.
7. Вернуть *blockValue*.

Отсюда видна суть:

1. Текущий *LexicalEnvironment* сохраняется,
2. Создается новый *LexicalEnvironment* и устанавливается в контекст выполнения
3. После выполнения выражения в контекст выполнения устанавливается сохраненный *LexicalEnvironment*

Comment: Все, понятно, благодарю.

Comment: @smellyshovel Новый контекст не создается при `Block:{ StatementList }`